# how to optimize speed excel 2007 (±20,000 rows)

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm in the process of working with an Excel file that contains two columns (old URL and new URL).  But it contains about 20,000 rows.

And I have another file containing about 400 old/new URL that needs to be imported in the big ±20,000 rows file.

I have to do all kinds of processing, like:
- Find all duplicate rows (same two columns more than once...).  That functionnality would be in a column and it would be good to run that function each time I add 1 row to check if that URL combination already exists in the file

Note that I already turned the sheet into a table.

2 questions now:

1) should I do some kind of vlookup from the ±20,000 rows sheet and the ±400 rows sheet, or VBA?  I don't know what would be the best way to do this (i.e.: if that row from the ±400 rows sheet is not in the ±20,000 rows sheet, add it...).  Should I use vlookups or populate arrays in VBA (speed-wise)?  If I use vlookup, it is true that it is possible to put the vlookup function in a sheet and refer to it in every row instead of puting a vlookup function directly in every row?

2) How can I optimize the 20,000 rows sheet because now, each time I want to sort or filter, it takes an eternity to redraw and it freeze my PC for that time!

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to ommit the dupes from the 400ish row sheet that need to be added in, use a COUNTIFS formula against the big sheet, then sort by this value and only copy in things where there is < 1 for the value (or error).

Secondly I would probably do the same thing in the big sheet but referencing itself, anything with a value above 1 is a dupe.

Lastly, are there formulas in the 20,000 row sheet? I could set up a 20,000 row sheet with just a "1" in range A1:A20,000 and doing anything on it would be super quick. It all comes down to what data you have in there and what you can do to reduce it's load on the system (ie convert formulas to values if they no longer need to calculated)

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2007 has a built-in feature and VBA you can use for your situation: `Range.RemoveDuplicates` or **Data** tab -> **Data Tools** group -> **Remove Duplicates**

For example data:
[image: Sample_Before]
Click the **Remove Duplicates** button:
[image: RemoveDuplicateButton]
[image: RemoveDuplicatePrompt]
[image: Results]
And you are done!
[image: Sample_After]

The VBA equivalent is:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$10").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
```

Note the 1 & 2 does not mean Columns A & B. It means the Columns of the selected Range.

If your worksheet only contains 2 columns, you could use `UsedRange` instead.